# Checking has_many :through with the conditions in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec3

```rb
class Company
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :roles,->{where("roles.created >= ?",Date.today-1.day)}through: :permissions
end

class Role
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :companies,through: :permissions
end

class Permission
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :company
end
```

How to do rspec testing for this kind of situations
it should have many roles

```rb
(roles.created_at >= Date.today-1.day)" do
    ass = Company.reflect_on_association(:roles)
    ass.macro.should == :has_many
    ass.options.should == {
      :through => :permissions,
      :conditions => "roles.created_at >= 05-02-2020",
    }
  end
```

But the spec has failed because the conditions method is deprecated there how to check the scope here and test the scope by where clause `"roles.created_at >= 05-02-2020"`

Comment: Why on earth would you want to add that condition to the roles association?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [shoulda matchers gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) which give you so many useful matchers. Here are ActiveRecord matchers
for [has many](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb) association. In your case it will be useful:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :coins, -> { where(quality: 'mint') }
end

# RSpec
RSpec.describe Person, type: :model do
  it { should have_many(:coins).conditions(quality: 'mint') }
end
```